# Sprint boot kafka Consumer can not connect to the kafka container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to deploy 2 Spring boot Apps (kafka Producer and Consumer). When I deploy the Producer to docker is all ok but when I deploy my Consumer doesn't work because doesn't have the connection with kafka container.

The log show me this error

```
2019-11-17 05:32:22.644  WARN 1 --- [main] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=exampleGroup] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

my docker-compose.yml is

```
version: '3'

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 2181:2181

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    links:
      - zookeeper:zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "topic1:1:1"
```

On my KafkaConfig class:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory(){
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KafkaConstants.KAFKA_BROKERS);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "exampleGroup");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
      //  config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, KafkaConstants.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, KafkaConstants.OFFSET_RESET_EARLIER);
       // config.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, KafkaConstants.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
    }
```

And the constants class

```
public class KafkaConstants {

    public static String KAFKA_BROKERS = "localhost:9092";
    public static Integer MESSAGE_COUNT=1000;
    public static String TOPIC_NAME="demo";
    public static String GROUP_ID_CONFIG="exampleGroup";
    public static Integer MAX_NO_MESSAGE_FOUND_COUNT=100;
    public static String OFFSET_RESET_LATEST="latest";
    public static String OFFSET_RESET_EARLIER="earliest";
    public static Integer MAX_POLL_RECORDS=1;
    public static Integer SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS = 180000;
    public static Integer REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG = 181000;
    public static String ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG = "false";
    public static Integer AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG = 8000;
}
```

When I install zookepper and kafka on my computer and run this 2 spring boot apps with intellij works fine. the problem is when I deploy to my local docker.

Can you please help me?

**UPDATE**

Updating my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 2181:2181

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    links:
      - zookeeper:zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "ACC_GROUP_CREATE:1:1"

  consumer:
    image: micro1
    container_name: micro1
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    links:
      - kafka:kafka

  producer:
    image: micro2
    container_name: micro2
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8087:8087
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    links:
      - kafka:kafka
```

Works fine! based on the response of @hqt but I don't know why I need to add these lines of Consumer/producer

Comment: try providing broker IP address with port

Comment: What do you mean? On the KafkaConfig class I already specified the host and the port

Comment: If you deployed your code "to docker", you can't use localhost as the Kafka Connection because that's the container itself, not the kafka one

Comment: @cricket_007 What should be the configuration of my sprint boot app or docker container because I also tried on the BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG to put the host/port like 0.0.0.0:9092 and have the same connection problem

Comment: Well, 0.0.0.0 isn't a valid ip address. The kafka container is called `kafka` , so your app should connect to `kafka:9092`

Comment: Add which lines of producer/consumer? How were you running the code as a container before?

Comment: @cricket_007 I runned only the docker-compose with the lines of zookepper and kafka and then I build/deploy my 2 spring boot apps by docker commands but by this way my consumer never see my kafka container, do you know why on this way doesn't work?

Comment: Because docker-compose creates its own bridge network. You would have to add `docker run --network` if you want to connect to it otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem because of the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` attribute. Here is the [documentation](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/) which explains why Kafka needs the advertised address.

> The key thing is that when you run a client, **the broker you pass to it
>   is just where it’s going to go and get the metadata about brokers in
>   the cluster from.** The actual host & IP that it will connect to for
>   reading/writing data is **based on the data that the broker passes back**
>   in that initial connection—even if it’s just a single node and the
>   broker returned is the same as the one connected to.

When you set `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` to the localhost:

- Your app which runs on "Intellij", that means run on the host environment. This host creates the Kafka's container so the access from localhost:9092 will point to the Kafka's container.
- When your app runs inside the container, localhost:9092 means the container itself. So it is meaningless. (This container even doesn't have any process which listens on port 9092)

Updating the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` attribute to `kafka` would work when running the web app inside the container environment. Noted that both of your web app and the kafka container must be on the same the docker's network.

Here is the proposed docker-compose for running the Kafka cluster using the Wurstmeister's image.

```
version: "2"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "topic1:1:1"

   web_app:
    # your definition of the web_app goes  here
```

Then you can connect to the Kafka brokers on the address `kafka:9092` inside the container environment.

Comment: localhost and 127.0.0.1 are the same thing, so why would that work? The advertised host name should be kafka

Comment: @cricket_007 My mistake. When typing the answer to the part docker-compose. I am thinking about he cannot connect to the kafka on the host environment, which does not correct. Thanks for pointing out this mistake.

Comment: @hqt changing ```KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME``` to kafka but adding on my docker-compose the individual config of the consumer and producer works fine! see my update part please

Comment: The reason you need to add the consumer image and the producer image on the same docker-compose to make those containers when running share the same network. Otherwise, they can not resolve `kafka:9092` address.
There are some better and recommend ways to make all the containers you want to share the same network, but this is the easiest to do for testing.

Comment: @hqt Where I can see the best practice or recommendations to make all the containers share the same network?

Comment: Keeping all services on the same compose file is not practical. Instead, you can try to execute each container with `--network  <predefined_network>` would be better.  
In the large system, we often use some provision tools such as `terraform`, configuration management tools such as `ansible`, or docker orchestration tools such as `nomad`,   `kubernetes` to set up the network layout. It is harder to set up but far easier to control in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem and the authoritative documentation you need to read and understand is https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained

I'm copying its tl;dr: for reference:

> You need to set advertised.listeners (or >KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS if you’re using Docker >images) to the external address (host/IP) so that clients >can correctly connect to it. Otherwise, they’ll try to connect >to the internal host address—and if that’s not reachable, >then problems ensue."